# How to customize the form in the edit view of a resource in Rails active_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a form in the edit view in my rails app and this edit view is that of a resource in the active_admin directory.

I know active admin used formtastic I cannot find a view template for the edit view.

If I want to change the form so that a field has a drop down menu instead of a type-in field. Where and how can I set this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:**

Inside of `app/admin/model_name.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register ModelName do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "ModelName" do
      f.input :title, :required => true
      f.input :name
      #
      # ... other inputs ...
      #
      f.input :foo, :as => :select, :collection => ModelName.all.map{ |x| [x.title, x.id] }
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

How it's done:

```
:as => :select
```

creates a select input

```
:collection => [ [text, value], [text, value] ...]
```

represent the options in the select input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Is this code part of formtastic? So I'll be able to find all the options and customization there?